# Regex expression replacing many "$" with different items in Google Sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I did not find any answers regarding my problem. Maybe I am just not so familiar with regex expressions.

I have the following cell in Google Sheets:

> $ goes $, and $ goes $.

I would like to replace those dollar signs with different items. Let's say I imagine it somehow like that:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(A1; "\$"; "John");"\$";"left");"\$";"Bill");"\$";"right")
```

.. but of course, it does not work as I would like, giving the results like:

> John goes John, and John goes John.

I wonder if I am able, just with some formula, to make it like this:

> John goes left, and Bill goes right.

Thanks!

Comment: You could use the following regex normally `(?:^[^$]*)(\$)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1; "\$([^$]*)\$([^$]*)\$([^$]*)\$", "John$1left$2Bill$3right")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OqtfaB/1).

If you need to replace the first occurrence, you can use

```sql
=REGEXREPLACE(A1; "^([^$]*)\$([^$]*)\$([^$]*)\$([^$]*)\$", "$1John$2left$3Bill$4right")
```

That is, you need to match and capture the parts between `$` chars and then use backreferences to these group values in the replacement pattern.

*Regex details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `([^$]*)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than `$`
- `\$` - a `$`
- `([^$]*)\$([^$]*)\$([^$]*)\$` - Group 2 with zero or more non-`$`s, a `$`, Group 3 with zero or more chars other than `$` and again a `$` and Group 4 with zero or more non-`$`s and the last `$`.

Comment: It works! I didn't know it's that simple :) Thank you very much!